# Won't Casper mean that the processing power of the network is reduced?

Tags: casper

Something just occurred to me. The whole point of Ethereum is to act as a giant global computer. Currently that computer utilises many thousands of GPUs.

When we switch to Casper I will end up mining something else and I will stake my Casper wallet on something like a raspberry pi, I'd imagine that lots of other people will do the same thing.

I understand that things will be more efficient without PoW but surely this huge drop in resources will impact the performance of smart contracts?

Joe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GPU is not used to execute Ethereum Virtual Machine (EVM) smart contracts, only CPU is used.

Every full node, even non mining ones, will execute transaction smart contract code using CPU.

GPU is only for mining (proof-of-work). Mining is a separate process from executing and validating transactions.